# Amount of clients which have seen an impression of a product before purchasing - most optimal answer for Billion-record table

Tags: sql, performance, client, product, exists

for a project I am working on I was asked to solve this task:

Given the table

events
event_id int (autoincrement) --**10B distinct values**
event_ts datetime -- **10B**
event_type int (1 = impression, 2 = click, 3 = purchase...) --20 types
product_id int  --100K
client_id int --10M
client_type int --10

**Q**: find the amount of clients which have seen an impression of a product before purchasing it

I came up with two solutions:

1)

```
With cteProdsClients As (
select e1.product_id ,e1.client_id 
from  events as e1
where event_type = ‘3’ and 

EXISTS (SELECT  e2.product_id ,e2.client_id 
              FROM events as e2
              WHERE event_type = ‘1’ and    e1.product_id  = e2.product_id 
                        AND e1.client_id  = e2.client_id
AND e1.event_ts  <e2.event_ts )

count(distinct product_id)
From cteProdsClients                    
)
SELECT
    count(distinct client_id)
FROM 
    cteProdsClients ;



2)

With cteProdsClients As (
select e1.product_id ,e1.client_id 
from  events as e1 left join 
(
  SELECT  e2.product_id ,e2.client_id 
              FROM events as e2   
 WHERE event_type = ‘1’  AND e1.event_ts  <e2.event_ts
)  
ON e1.product_id  = e2.product_id  AND e1.client_id  = e2.client_id
WHERE event_type = ‘3’ 
)
SELECT
    count(distinct client_id)
FROM 
    cteProdsClients ;
```

I need to not only create a query that would get the output but also do it in the most efficient, optimized way. Out of these 2 which is better? I would appreciate it if you fixed errors (if exist) and propose better solutions
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overcomplicating things; I believe this will give you what you want. Performance would be dependent on appropriate indexing, etc.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT E1.CLIENT_ID)
FROM EVENTS E1
INNER JOIN EVENTS E2 ON 
    E1.CLIENT_ID = E2.CLIENT_ID AND
    E1.PRODUCT_ID = E2.PRODUCT_ID AND
    E1.EVENT_TS < E2.EVENT_TS AND 
    E2.EVENT_TYPE = '3'
WHERE E1.EVENT_TYPE = '1'
```

Comment: thanks. seems like it would work. 
though performance-wise, I guess the join on a few columns would not be ideal. is there a better suggestion? @Nickw

Comment: hows this?
WITH cteProdsClients AS (
    SELECT product_id, client_id, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN event_type = '1' THEN event_ts ELSE NULL END) AS first_impression,
        MIN(CASE WHEN event_type = '3' THEN event_ts ELSE NULL END) AS first_purchase
    FROM events
    WHERE event_type IN ('1', '3')
    GROUP BY product_id, client_id
    HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND
       MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) AS client_count
FROM cteProdsClients
WHERE first_impression < first_purchase

Comment: Again, you are just over-complicating/over-thinking things. There is no theoretical best way of writing a SQL statement - you just need to write one, test it and then tune it if the performance is not acceptable. For you to come up with endless different SQL statements that produce the same result is just wasting time

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear.
This is a theoretical task, there isn't an actual database I could test this on...
I need to propose an optimal way (or one of)  @NickW

Comment: Then the optimal way is the simplest possible query (because I’m equating optimal with simplicity) I.e. the one I proposed. To consider anything else would require information about the actual DBMS, indexing, etc and as you don’t have any of that information it’s pointless going down the path of what-ifs as you have no criteria by which to judge any of the alternatives